# Is there a way of identifying if a given class has any references to another class?

Tags: c#, reflection, class-hierarchy

I can work through the hierarchy with reflection, yes, but it is challenging, because the elements are diverse. So:

```
class A
{
    string Hello;
}

class B
{
    List<A> Hellos;
}

class E
{
    A OtherRandomness;
}
class D:B
{
   E randomthing;
}

class C:D
{
    string OtherThing;
}
```

I have an object that is of type C, and I want to be able to find and identify that this has, down the line, a list of A object, and then to process them.

The real life example is a more complex hierarchy than this, of course, but the principle is the same. I have tried a recursive loop through the properties, but I was struggling to find ways of dealing with a) not trying to process string and int objects and b) identifying that a property was something like an enumerable of X. Related is the fact that there might be enumerables of classes that inherit from A.

If anyone can suggest an approach that would make this straightforward, that would be appreciated. I need to be able to do this in a range of places, so I have to be able to start with any class type.

So I start with a type of x. In this case x is C, but x could just as easily be Z, with no links to type A.

Also, this needs to pick up whether I have class D in or not. I want to be able to pick up Hellos and randomthing.

Comment: I think you oversimplified your scenario. Right now, this is as simple as `var c = new C(); foreach (var a in c.Hellos) { ... }`

Comment: I have just added - that I need to be able to start from a type reference. So I don't know if the type I have has "Hellos" on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that these are public instance properties. If you want something else, you can adapt the `BindingFlags`.

The idea of my solution is to test whether the type of the property is generic. If yes, it tests whether one of the type arguments is `typeof(A)`. However, It does not test nested generic types like `List<List<A>>`. This would require a recursive approach.

```cs
var props = typeof(C).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                p.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.Any(t => t == typeof(A)));
foreach (var prop in props) {
    Console.WriteLine(prop);
}
```

prints:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyNamespace.A] Hellos

---

More specifically testing for enumerations of A using this type hierarchy:

```cs
class A
{
    public string Hello { get; set; }
}

class AA : A
{
}

class B
{
    public List<A> Hellos { get; set; }
    public List<AA> AAHellos { get; set; }
}

class D : B
{
    public A randomthing { get; set; }
}

class C : D
{
    public string OtherThing { get; set; }
}
```

Test:

```cs
var c = new C {
    Hellos = new List<A> {
        new A { Hello = "Hello" },
        new A { Hello = "World" }
    },
    AAHellos = new List<AA> {
        new AA { Hello = "Hello" },
        new AA { Hello = "World AA" }
    }
};
var enumerableOfA = typeof(IEnumerable<A>);
var props = c.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Where(p => enumerableOfA.IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType));
foreach (var prop in props) {
    Console.WriteLine(prop);
    var list = (IEnumerable<A>)prop.GetValue(c);
    foreach (var item in list) {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Hello);
    }
}
```

prints:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyNamespace.A] Hellos
> Hello
> World
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyNamespace.AA] AAHellos
> Hello AA
> World AA

It might be surprising that this returns lists of `AA` as well. It happens because of the `out` keyword in the declaration of the interface `IEnumerable<out T>`  making it covariant.

This will, however, not include, e.g. `Dictionary<int,A>`, because the dictionary implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,A>>`. My first solution would return such a property, but then it would require more work to get dictionary entries.

Comment: Broadly yes, but this hierarchy may go layers more deep. I am going to update teh example somewhat.

Comment: The depth of the hierarchy doesn't change anything, as you will automatically see all the inherited properties.

Comment: Hmm - OK. I need to see if this will work as I expect. THank you.

Comment: OK, this works pretty well, but I have now added another route that I have found in my real system. Where the property itself does not reference A, but a property on the property does.

Comment: Okay, then you must apply this recursively to objects referenced by a property. You can exclude primitive types by testing for the [Type.IsPrimitive Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive?view=net-6.0).

Comment: That is cool. I think I wanted to also handle where there might be lists or dictionaries or tuples including type D , but I can work around these.